# Skyscraper Solver for NxN Size Version 2 (Using Backtracking)

Tags: c++, performance, c++17

This is a follow up of [Skyscraper Solver for NxN Size](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256579/skyscraper-solver-for-nxn-size)

I followed the advice in the last question and changed my approach from generating Permutations to use [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to solve the puzzle.

Unfortunately my solution is still to slow for certain tests.

Here are the worst test cases:

```
struct TestDataProvider {
    std::vector<int> clues;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> board;
};

TestDataProvider sky7_random{{0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3,
                              6, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4},
                             {{{2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 7},
                               {7, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6},
                               {6, 4, 2, 3, 1, 7, 5},
                               {4, 5, 7, 6, 2, 3, 1},
                               {3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4},
                               {1, 6, 4, 7, 5, 2, 3},
                               {5, 7, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2}}}};
                                  
                                 

TestDataProvider sky11_medium_partial_2{
    {1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4,
     3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1},
    {{11, 9, 10, 5, 8, 6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 7},
     {9, 1, 3, 8, 7, 11, 6, 5, 2, 4, 10},
     {6, 2, 1, 7, 3, 9, 8, 11, 5, 10, 4},
     {7, 6, 4, 2, 10, 8, 1, 3, 9, 5, 11},
     {2, 7, 6, 9, 4, 10, 3, 8, 11, 1, 5},
     {4, 11, 2, 6, 9, 5, 10, 1, 3, 7, 8},
     {1, 4, 7, 10, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 9},
     {3, 8, 5, 4, 11, 7, 9, 2, 10, 6, 1},
     {10, 5, 8, 1, 6, 2, 11, 7, 4, 9, 3},
     {5, 10, 11, 3, 1, 4, 7, 9, 6, 8, 2},
     {8, 3, 9, 11, 5, 1, 4, 10, 7, 2, 6}},
    {{0, 0, 10, 0, 8, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 11, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 9, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 11, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 6, 9, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 8},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9},
     {0, 0, 0, 4, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
     {10, 0, 8, 1, 0, 2, 11, 7, 4, 0, 0},
     {5, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0},
     {0, 0, 9, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 6}}};

     
TEST(CodewarsBacktracking, sky7_random)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(codewarsbacktracking::SolvePuzzle(sky7_random.clues),
              sky7_random.result);
}


TEST(CodewarsBacktracking, sky11_medium_partial_2)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(codewarsbacktracking::SolvePuzzle(
                  sky11_medium_partial_2.clues, sky11_medium_partial_2.board,
                  sky11_medium_partial_2.board.size()),
              sky11_medium_partial_2.result);
}
```

The first test tries to solve a 7x7 Board with no skyscrapers on the grid. A few Skyscrapers are computed out of the clues provided but then my backtracking routine needs to insert ~440 mio times until the puzzle is solved.

The other test case is a 11x11 board which is already partially filled but also has not many clues.

On my system the run times look like this in release mode (Including other unit tests which are a lot faster):

```
[----------] 35 tests from CodewarsBacktracking
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_easy
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_easy (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_easy_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_easy_2 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_hard
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_hard (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_hard_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_hard_2 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_easy
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_easy (5 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_medium
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_medium (3 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_hard
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_hard (5 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_hard_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_hard_2 (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_random
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_random (13 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_random_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_random_2 (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_random_3
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_random_3 (3 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_medium
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_medium (27 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_hard
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_hard (54 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_very_hard
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_very_hard (336 ms)
    [ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_random
    [       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_random (72952 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_partial (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_partial_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky4_partial_2 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky5_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky5_partial (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky5_partial_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky5_partial_2 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_partial (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_partial_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky6_partial_2 (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_easy_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_easy_partial (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_easy_partial_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_easy_partial_2 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_medium_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_medium_partial (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_hard_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky7_hard_partial (42 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky8_easy_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky8_easy_partial (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky8_medium_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky8_medium_partial (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky8_hard_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky8_hard_partial (1390 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky9_easy_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky9_easy_partial (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky9_easy_partial_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky9_easy_partial_2 (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky10_easy_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky10_easy_partial (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky10_easy_partial_2
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky10_easy_partial_2 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky11_easy_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky11_easy_partial (2 ms)
[ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky11_medium_partial
[       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky11_medium_partial (661 ms)
    [ RUN      ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky11_medium_partial_2
    [       OK ] CodewarsBacktracking.sky11_medium_partial_2 (36910 ms)
[----------] 35 tests from CodewarsBacktracking (112413 ms total)
```

So I wonder is there any way to make the backtracking faster here or is there just no faster way to solve skyscraper puzzles? Is it possible to reduce the calls to the backtracking routine ?

I already try to abort the insertion as soon as the board is getting invalid. I cannot come up with another tweak to reduce the backtracking calls.

Below the full code for the backtracking.

The interesting part which does the backtracking is the function `guessSkyscrapers`:

```
bool guessSkyscrapers(Board &board, const std::vector<int> &clues,
                      std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t size)
{
    if (x == size) {
        x = 0;
        y++;
    };
    if (y == size) {
        return true;
    }
    if (board.skyscrapers[y][x] != 0) {
        if (!skyscrapersAreValidPositioned(board.skyscrapers, clues, x, y,
                                           size)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (guessSkyscrapers(board, clues, x + 1, y, size)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (int trySkyscraper = 1;
         trySkyscraper <= static_cast<int>(board.skyscrapers.size());
         ++trySkyscraper) {

        if (board.nopes[y][x].contains(trySkyscraper)) {
            continue;
        }
        board.skyscrapers[y][x] = trySkyscraper;
        if (!skyscrapersAreValidPositioned(board.skyscrapers, clues, x, y,
                                           size)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (guessSkyscrapers(board, clues, x + 1, y, size)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    board.skyscrapers[y][x] = 0;
    return false;
}
```

Let me know if you have any idea how to speed up solving this puzzles.

If you want to see the whole github project which contains:

-Backtracking Solution in one file (like here requirement for codewars)
-Backtracking Solution in multiple files
-Permutations Solution in one file (like here requirement for codewars)
-Permutations Solution in multiple files
-Full Unit test suite

You can find it [here](https://github.com/SandroWissmann/Skyscrapers)

Full backtracking code:

**codewarsbacktracking.cpp**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

namespace codewarsbacktracking {

struct ClueHints {
    ClueHints(std::size_t boardSize);
    ClueHints();

    void reverse();

    void removeNopesOnSkyscrapers();

    std::vector<int> skyscrapers{};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> nopes{};
};

ClueHints::ClueHints(std::size_t boardSize)
    : skyscrapers{std::vector<int>(boardSize, 0)},
      nopes{std::vector<std::vector<int>>(boardSize, std::vector<int>{})}
{
}

void ClueHints::reverse()
{
    std::reverse(skyscrapers.begin(), skyscrapers.end());
    std::reverse(nopes.begin(), nopes.end());
}

void ClueHints::removeNopesOnSkyscrapers()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < skyscrapers.size(); ++i) {
        if (skyscrapers[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        nopes[i].clear();
    }
}

std::optional<ClueHints> getClueHints(int clue, std::size_t boardSize)
{
    if (clue == 0) {
        return {};
    }

    ClueHints clueHints{boardSize};

    std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> nopes(boardSize,
                                               std::unordered_set<int>{});

    if (clue == static_cast<int>(boardSize)) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < boardSize; ++i) {
            clueHints.skyscrapers[i] = i + 1;
        }
    }
    else if (clue == 1) {
        clueHints.skyscrapers[0] = boardSize;
    }
    else if (clue == 2) {
        nopes[0].insert(boardSize);
        nopes[1].insert(boardSize - 1);
    }
    else {
        for (std::size_t fieldIdx = 0;
             fieldIdx < static_cast<std::size_t>(clue - 1); ++fieldIdx) {

            for (std::size_t nopeValue = boardSize;
                 nopeValue >= (boardSize - (clue - 2) + fieldIdx);
                 --nopeValue) {
                nopes[fieldIdx].insert(nopeValue);
            }
        }
    }

    assert(nopes.size() == clueHints.nopes.size());

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nopes.size(); ++i) {
        clueHints.nopes[i] = std::vector<int>(nopes[i].begin(), nopes[i].end());
    }
    return {clueHints};
}

std::optional<ClueHints> merge(std::optional<ClueHints> optFrontClueHints,
                               std::optional<ClueHints> optBackClueHints)
{
    if (!optFrontClueHints && !optBackClueHints) {
        return {};
    }
    if (!optFrontClueHints) {
        optBackClueHints->reverse();
        return optBackClueHints;
    }
    if (!optBackClueHints) {
        return optFrontClueHints;
    }

    auto size = optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers.size();
    ClueHints clueHints{size};

    assert(optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers.size() ==
           optFrontClueHints->nopes.size());
    assert(optBackClueHints->skyscrapers.size() ==
           optBackClueHints->nopes.size());
    assert(optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers.size() ==
           optBackClueHints->skyscrapers.size());

    optBackClueHints->reverse();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers.size(); ++i) {

        auto frontSkyscraper = optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers[i];
        auto backSkyscraper = optBackClueHints->skyscrapers[i];

        if (frontSkyscraper != 0 && backSkyscraper != 0) {
            assert(frontSkyscraper == backSkyscraper);
            clueHints.skyscrapers[i] = frontSkyscraper;
        }
        else if (frontSkyscraper != 0) {
            clueHints.skyscrapers[i] = frontSkyscraper;
            clueHints.nopes[i].clear();
        }
        else { // backSkyscraper != 0
            clueHints.skyscrapers[i] = backSkyscraper;
            clueHints.nopes[i].clear();
        }

        if (clueHints.skyscrapers[i] != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        std::unordered_set<int> nopes(optFrontClueHints->nopes[i].begin(),
                                      optFrontClueHints->nopes[i].end());
        nopes.insert(optBackClueHints->nopes[i].begin(),
                     optBackClueHints->nopes[i].end());
        clueHints.nopes[i] = std::vector<int>(nopes.begin(), nopes.end());
    }
    clueHints.removeNopesOnSkyscrapers();
    return {clueHints};
}

void mergeClueHintsPerRow(std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>> &clueHints)
{
    std::size_t startOffset = clueHints.size() / 4 * 3 - 1;
    std::size_t offset = startOffset;

    for (std::size_t frontIdx = 0; frontIdx < clueHints.size() / 2;
         ++frontIdx, offset -= 2) {

        if (frontIdx == clueHints.size() / 4) {
            offset = startOffset;
        }

        int backIdx = frontIdx + offset;

        clueHints[frontIdx] = merge(clueHints[frontIdx], clueHints[backIdx]);
    }
    clueHints.erase(clueHints.begin() + clueHints.size() / 2, clueHints.end());
}

std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>>
getClueHints(const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t boardSize)
{
    std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>> clueHints;
    clueHints.reserve(clues.size());

    for (const auto &clue : clues) {
        clueHints.emplace_back(getClueHints(clue, boardSize));
    }
    mergeClueHintsPerRow(clueHints);
    return clueHints;
}

template <typename It> int missingNumberInSequence(It begin, It end)
{
    int n = std::distance(begin, end) + 1;
    double projectedSum = (n + 1) * (n / 2.0);
    int actualSum = std::accumulate(begin, end, 0);
    return projectedSum - actualSum;
}

class Nopes {
public:
    Nopes(int size);

    void insert(int value);
    void insert(const std::vector<int> &values);
    bool sizeReached() const;
    int missingNumberInSequence() const;

    bool contains(int value) const;
    bool contains(const std::vector<int> &values);

    bool isEmpty() const;
    void clear();

    std::vector<int> containing() const;

    // for debug print
    std::unordered_set<int> values() const;

private:
    int mSize;
    std::unordered_set<int> mValues;
};

Nopes::Nopes(int size) : mSize{size}
{
    assert(size > 0);
}

void Nopes::insert(int value)
{
    assert(value >= 1 && value <= mSize + 1);
    mValues.insert(value);
}

void Nopes::insert(const std::vector<int> &values)
{
    mValues.insert(values.begin(), values.end());
}

bool Nopes::sizeReached() const
{
    return mValues.size() == static_cast<std::size_t>(mSize);
}

int Nopes::missingNumberInSequence() const
{
    assert(sizeReached());
    return codewarsbacktracking::missingNumberInSequence(mValues.begin(),
                                                         mValues.end());
}

bool Nopes::contains(int value) const
{
    auto it = mValues.find(value);
    return it != mValues.end();
}

bool Nopes::contains(const std::vector<int> &values)
{
    for (const auto &value : values) {
        if (!contains(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Nopes::isEmpty() const
{
    return mValues.empty();
}

void Nopes::clear()
{
    mValues.clear();
}

std::vector<int> Nopes::containing() const
{
    std::vector<int> nopes;
    nopes.reserve(mValues.size());
    for (const auto &value : mValues) {
        nopes.emplace_back(value);
    }
    return nopes;
}

std::unordered_set<int> Nopes::values() const
{
    return mValues;
}

class Field {
public:
    Field(int &skyscraper, Nopes &nopes);

    void insertSkyscraper(int skyscraper);
    void insertNope(int nope);
    void insertNopes(const std::vector<int> &nopes);

    bool fullOfNopes() const;

    int skyscraper() const;
    Nopes nopes() const;

    bool hasSkyscraper() const;

    std::optional<int> lastMissingNope() const;

private:
    int &mSkyscraper;
    Nopes &mNopes;
    bool mHasSkyscraper = false;
};

Field::Field(int &skyscraper, Nopes &nopes)
    : mSkyscraper{skyscraper}, mNopes{nopes}
{
}

void Field::insertSkyscraper(int skyscraper)
{
    assert(mSkyscraper == 0 || skyscraper == mSkyscraper);
    if (mHasSkyscraper) {
        return;
    }
    mSkyscraper = skyscraper;
    mHasSkyscraper = true;

    mNopes.clear();
}
void Field::insertNope(int nope)
{
    if (mHasSkyscraper) {
        return;
    }
    mNopes.insert(nope);
}
void Field::insertNopes(const std::vector<int> &nopes)
{
    if (mHasSkyscraper) {
        return;
    }
    mNopes.insert(nopes);
}

bool Field::fullOfNopes() const
{
    return mNopes.sizeReached();
}

int Field::skyscraper() const
{
    return mSkyscraper;
}
Nopes Field::nopes() const
{
    return mNopes;
}

bool Field::hasSkyscraper() const
{
    return mHasSkyscraper;
}

std::optional<int> Field::lastMissingNope() const
{
    if (!mNopes.sizeReached()) {
        return {};
    }
    return mNopes.missingNumberInSequence();
}

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

inline bool operator==(const Point &lhs, const Point &rhs)
{
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}
inline bool operator!=(const Point &lhs, const Point &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

enum class ReadDirection { topToBottom, rightToLeft };

void nextDirection(ReadDirection &readDirection);

void advanceToNextPosition(Point &point, ReadDirection readDirection,
                           int clueIdx);

void nextDirection(ReadDirection &readDirection)
{
    assert(readDirection != ReadDirection::rightToLeft);
    int dir = static_cast<int>(readDirection);
    ++dir;
    readDirection = static_cast<ReadDirection>(dir);
}

void advanceToNextPosition(Point &point, ReadDirection readDirection,
                           int clueIdx)
{
    if (clueIdx == 0) {
        return;
    }
    switch (readDirection) {
    case ReadDirection::topToBottom:
        ++point.x;
        break;
    case ReadDirection::rightToLeft:
        ++point.y;
        break;
    }
}

class Row {
public:
    Row(std::vector<std::vector<Field>> &fields, const Point &startPoint,
        const ReadDirection &readDirection);

    void insertSkyscraper(int pos, int skyscraper);

    std::size_t size() const;

    void addCrossingRows(Row *crossingRow);

    bool hasOnlyOneNopeField() const;
    void addLastMissingSkyscraper();

    void addNopesToAllNopeFields(int nope);

    bool allFieldsContainSkyscraper() const;

    int skyscraperCount() const;
    int nopeCount(int nope) const;

    void guessSkyscraperOutOfNeighbourNopes();

    enum class Direction { front, back };

    bool hasSkyscrapers(const std::vector<int> &skyscrapers,
                        Direction direction) const;
    bool hasNopes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &nopes,
                  Direction direction) const;

    void addSkyscrapers(const std::vector<int> &skyscrapers,
                        Direction direction);
    void addNopes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &nopes,
                  Direction direction);

    std::vector<Field *> getFields() const;

private:
    template <typename SkyIterator, typename FieldIterator>
    bool hasSkyscrapers(SkyIterator skyItBegin, SkyIterator skyItEnd,
                        FieldIterator fieldItBegin,
                        FieldIterator fieldItEnd) const;

    template <typename NopesIterator, typename FieldIterator>
    bool hasNopes(NopesIterator nopesItBegin, NopesIterator nopesItEnd,
                  FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd) const;

    template <typename SkyIterator, typename FieldIterator>
    void addSkyscrapers(SkyIterator skyItBegin, SkyIterator skyItEnd,
                        FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd);

    template <typename NopesIterator, typename FieldIterator>
    void addNopes(NopesIterator nopesItBegin, NopesIterator nopesItEnd,
                  FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd);

    template <typename IteratorType>
    void insertSkyscraper(IteratorType it, int skyscraper);

    template <typename IteratorType> void insertNope(IteratorType it, int nope);

    template <typename IteratorType>
    void insertNopes(IteratorType it, const std::vector<int> &nopes);

    int getIdx(std::vector<Field *>::const_iterator cit) const;
    int getIdx(std::vector<Field *>::const_reverse_iterator crit) const;

    std::vector<Field *> getRowFields(const ReadDirection &readDirection,
                                      std::vector<std::vector<Field>> &fields,
                                      const Point &startPoint);

    bool onlyOneFieldWithoutNope(int nope) const;
    std::optional<int> nopeValueInAllButOneField() const;

    void insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(int nope);

    bool hasSkyscraper(int skyscraper) const;

    std::vector<Row *> mCrossingRows;
    std::vector<Field *> mRowFields;
};

Row::Row(std::vector<std::vector<Field>> &fields, const Point &startPoint,
         const ReadDirection &readDirection)
    : mRowFields{getRowFields(readDirection, fields, startPoint)}
{
}

void Row::insertSkyscraper(int pos, int skyscraper)
{
    assert(pos >= 0 && pos < static_cast<int>(mRowFields.size()));
    assert(skyscraper > 0 && skyscraper <= static_cast<int>(mRowFields.size()));
    auto it = mRowFields.begin() + pos;
    insertSkyscraper(it, skyscraper);
}

std::size_t Row::size() const
{
    return mRowFields.size();
}

void Row::addCrossingRows(Row *crossingRow)
{
    assert(crossingRow != nullptr);
    assert(mCrossingRows.size() < size());
    mCrossingRows.push_back(crossingRow);
}

bool Row::hasOnlyOneNopeField() const
{
    return skyscraperCount() == static_cast<int>(size() - 1);
}

void Row::addLastMissingSkyscraper()
{
    assert(hasOnlyOneNopeField());

    auto nopeFieldIt = mRowFields.end();
    std::vector<int> sequence;
    sequence.reserve(size() - 1);

    for (auto it = mRowFields.begin(); it != mRowFields.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            sequence.emplace_back((*it)->skyscraper());
        }
        else {
            nopeFieldIt = it;
        }
    }
    assert(nopeFieldIt != mRowFields.end());
    assert(skyscraperCount() == static_cast<int>(sequence.size()));
    auto missingValue =
        missingNumberInSequence(sequence.begin(), sequence.end());
    assert(missingValue >= 0 && missingValue <= static_cast<int>(size()));
    insertSkyscraper(nopeFieldIt, missingValue);
}

void Row::addNopesToAllNopeFields(int nope)
{
    for (auto it = mRowFields.begin(); it != mRowFields.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            continue;
        }
        insertNope(it, nope);
    }
}

bool Row::allFieldsContainSkyscraper() const
{
    return skyscraperCount() == static_cast<int>(size());
}

int Row::skyscraperCount() const
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto cit = mRowFields.cbegin(); cit != mRowFields.cend(); ++cit) {
        if ((*cit)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int Row::nopeCount(int nope) const
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto cit = mRowFields.cbegin(); cit != mRowFields.cend(); ++cit) {
        if ((*cit)->nopes().contains(nope)) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void Row::guessSkyscraperOutOfNeighbourNopes()
{
    for (;;) {
        auto optNope = nopeValueInAllButOneField();
        if (!optNope) {
            break;
        }
        insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(*optNope);
    }
}

bool Row::hasSkyscrapers(const std::vector<int> &skyscrapers,
                         Row::Direction direction) const
{
    if (direction == Direction::front) {
        return hasSkyscrapers(skyscrapers.cbegin(), skyscrapers.cend(),
                              mRowFields.cbegin(), mRowFields.cend());
    }
    return hasSkyscrapers(skyscrapers.cbegin(), skyscrapers.cend(),
                          mRowFields.crbegin(), mRowFields.crend());
}

bool Row::hasNopes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &nopes,
                   Direction direction) const
{
    if (direction == Direction::front) {
        return hasNopes(nopes.cbegin(), nopes.cend(), mRowFields.cbegin(),
                        mRowFields.cend());
    }
    return hasNopes(nopes.cbegin(), nopes.cend(), mRowFields.crbegin(),
                    mRowFields.crend());
}

void Row::addSkyscrapers(const std::vector<int> &skyscrapers,
                         Direction direction)
{
    if (direction == Direction::front) {
        addSkyscrapers(skyscrapers.begin(), skyscrapers.end(),
                       mRowFields.begin(), mRowFields.end());
    }
    else {
        addSkyscrapers(skyscrapers.begin(), skyscrapers.end(),
                       mRowFields.rbegin(), mRowFields.rend());
    }
}
void Row::addNopes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &nopes,
                   Direction direction)
{
    if (direction == Direction::front) {
        addNopes(nopes.begin(), nopes.end(), mRowFields.begin(),
                 mRowFields.end());
    }
    else {
        addNopes(nopes.begin(), nopes.end(), mRowFields.rbegin(),
                 mRowFields.rend());
    }
}

std::vector<Field *> Row::getFields() const
{
    return mRowFields;
}

template <typename SkyIterator, typename FieldIterator>
bool Row::hasSkyscrapers(SkyIterator skyItBegin, SkyIterator skyItEnd,
                         FieldIterator fieldItBegin,
                         FieldIterator fieldItEnd) const
{
    auto skyIt = skyItBegin;
    for (auto fieldIt = fieldItBegin;
         fieldIt != fieldItEnd && skyIt != skyItEnd; ++fieldIt, ++skyIt) {
        if (*skyIt == 0 && (*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((*fieldIt)->skyscraper() != *skyIt) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename NopesIterator, typename FieldIterator>
bool Row::hasNopes(NopesIterator nopesItBegin, NopesIterator nopesItEnd,
                   FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd) const
{
    auto nopesIt = nopesItBegin;
    for (auto fieldIt = fieldItBegin;
         fieldIt != fieldItEnd && nopesIt != nopesItEnd; ++fieldIt, ++nopesIt) {

        if (nopesIt->empty()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(*fieldIt)->nopes().contains(*nopesIt)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename SkyIterator, typename FieldIterator>
void Row::addSkyscrapers(SkyIterator skyItBegin, SkyIterator skyItEnd,
                         FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd)
{
    auto skyIt = skyItBegin;
    for (auto fieldIt = fieldItBegin;
         fieldIt != fieldItEnd && skyIt != skyItEnd; ++fieldIt, ++skyIt) {
        if (*skyIt == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        insertSkyscraper(fieldIt, *skyIt);
    }
}

template <typename NopesIterator, typename FieldIterator>
void Row::addNopes(NopesIterator nopesItBegin, NopesIterator nopesItEnd,
                   FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd)
{
    auto nopesIt = nopesItBegin;
    for (auto fieldIt = fieldItBegin;
         fieldIt != fieldItEnd && nopesIt != nopesItEnd; ++fieldIt, ++nopesIt) {
        if (nopesIt->empty()) {
            continue;
        }
        insertNopes(fieldIt, *nopesIt);
    }
}

template <typename FieldIterator>
void Row::insertSkyscraper(FieldIterator fieldIt, int skyscraper)
{
    assert(mCrossingRows.size() == size());

    if ((*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
        return;
    }
    (*fieldIt)->insertSkyscraper(skyscraper);

    if (hasOnlyOneNopeField()) {
        addLastMissingSkyscraper();
    }
    addNopesToAllNopeFields(skyscraper);

    int idx = getIdx(fieldIt);

    if (mCrossingRows[idx]->hasOnlyOneNopeField()) {
        mCrossingRows[idx]->addLastMissingSkyscraper();
    }

    mCrossingRows[idx]->addNopesToAllNopeFields(skyscraper);
}

template <typename FieldIterator>
void Row::insertNope(FieldIterator fieldIt, int nope)
{
    if ((*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
        return;
    }
    if ((*fieldIt)->nopes().contains(nope)) {
        return;
    }
    (*fieldIt)->insertNope(nope);

    auto optlastMissingNope = (*fieldIt)->lastMissingNope();
    if (optlastMissingNope) {
        insertSkyscraper(fieldIt, *optlastMissingNope);
    }

    if (onlyOneFieldWithoutNope(nope)) {
        insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(nope);
    }

    int idx = getIdx(fieldIt);

    if (mCrossingRows[idx]->onlyOneFieldWithoutNope(nope)) {
        mCrossingRows[idx]->insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(nope);
    }
}

template <typename IteratorType>
void Row::insertNopes(IteratorType it, const std::vector<int> &nopes)
{
    for (const auto &nope : nopes) {
        insertNope(it, nope);
    }
}

int Row::getIdx(std::vector<Field *>::const_iterator cit) const
{
    return std::distance(mRowFields.cbegin(), cit);
}

int Row::getIdx(std::vector<Field *>::const_reverse_iterator crit) const
{
    return size() - std::distance(mRowFields.crbegin(), crit) - 1;
}

std::vector<Field *>
Row::getRowFields(const ReadDirection &readDirection,
                  std::vector<std::vector<Field>> &boardFields,
                  const Point &startPoint)
{
    std::vector<Field *> fields;
    fields.reserve(boardFields.size());
    std::size_t x = startPoint.x;
    std::size_t y = startPoint.y;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < boardFields.size(); ++i) {
        fields.emplace_back(&boardFields[y][x]);

        if (readDirection == ReadDirection::topToBottom) {
            ++y;
        }
        else {
            --x;
        }
    }
    return fields;
}

bool Row::onlyOneFieldWithoutNope(int nope) const
{
    auto cit = std::find_if(
        mRowFields.cbegin(), mRowFields.cend(),
        [nope](const auto &field) { return field->skyscraper() == nope; });
    if (cit != mRowFields.cend()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (nopeCount(nope) < static_cast<int>(size()) - skyscraperCount() - 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

std::optional<int> Row::nopeValueInAllButOneField() const
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> nopeAndCount;

    for (auto cit = mRowFields.cbegin(); cit != mRowFields.cend(); ++cit) {
        if (!(*cit)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            auto nopes = (*cit)->nopes().containing();
            for (const auto &nope : nopes) {
                if (hasSkyscraper(nope)) {
                    continue;
                }
                ++nopeAndCount[nope];
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto cit = nopeAndCount.cbegin(); cit != nopeAndCount.end(); ++cit) {
        if (cit->second == static_cast<int>(size()) - skyscraperCount() - 1) {
            return {cit->first};
        }
    }
    return {};
}

void Row::insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(int nope)
{
    for (auto it = mRowFields.begin(); it != mRowFields.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!(*it)->nopes().contains(nope)) {
            insertSkyscraper(it, nope);
            return; // there can be max one skyscraper per row;
        }
    }
}

bool Row::hasSkyscraper(int skyscraper) const
{
    for (const auto &field : mRowFields) {
        if (field->skyscraper() == skyscraper) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

class BorderIterator {
public:
    BorderIterator(std::size_t boardSize);

    Point point() const;
    ReadDirection readDirection() const;

    BorderIterator &operator++();

private:
    int mIdx = 0;
    std::size_t mBoardSize;
    Point mPoint{0, 0};
    ReadDirection mReadDirection{ReadDirection::topToBottom};
};

BorderIterator::BorderIterator(std::size_t boardSize) : mBoardSize{boardSize}
{
}

Point BorderIterator::point() const
{
    return mPoint;
}

ReadDirection BorderIterator::readDirection() const
{
    return mReadDirection;
}

BorderIterator &BorderIterator::operator++()
{
    ++mIdx;
    if (mIdx == static_cast<int>(2 * mBoardSize)) {
        return *this;
    }
    if (mIdx != 0 && mIdx % mBoardSize == 0) {
        nextDirection(mReadDirection);
    }

    advanceToNextPosition(mPoint, mReadDirection, mIdx % mBoardSize);
    return *this;
}

struct Board {
    Board(std::size_t size);

    void insert(const std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>> &clueHints);

    void insert(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &startingSkyscrapers);

    bool isSolved() const;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> skyscrapers{};
    std::vector<std::vector<Nopes>> nopes;

    std::vector<Row> mRows;

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> makeSkyscrapers(std::size_t size);
    std::vector<std::vector<Nopes>> makeNopes(std::size_t size);

    void makeFields();
    void makeRows();
    void connnectRowsWithCrossingRows();

    std::vector<std::vector<Field>> mFields;
};

Board::Board(std::size_t size)
    : skyscrapers{makeSkyscrapers(size)}, nopes{makeNopes(size)},
      mFields{std::vector<std::vector<Field>>(skyscrapers.size())}
{
    makeFields();
    makeRows();
}

void Board::insert(const std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>> &clueHints)
{
    assert(clueHints.size() == mRows.size());

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < clueHints.size(); ++i) {
        if (!clueHints[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        mRows[i].addNopes(clueHints[i]->nopes, Row::Direction::front);
        mRows[i].addSkyscrapers(clueHints[i]->skyscrapers,
                                Row::Direction::front);
    }
}

void Board::insert(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &startingSkyscrapers)
{
    if (startingSkyscrapers.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    std::size_t boardSize = mRows.size() / 2;
    assert(startingSkyscrapers.size() == boardSize);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < startingSkyscrapers.size(); ++i) {
        mRows[i + boardSize].addSkyscrapers(startingSkyscrapers[i],
                                            Row::Direction::back);
    }
}

bool Board::isSolved() const
{
    std::size_t endVerticalRows = mRows.size() / 2;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < endVerticalRows; ++i) {
        if (!mRows[i].allFieldsContainSkyscraper()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> Board::makeSkyscrapers(std::size_t size)
{
    std::vector<int> skyscraperRow(size, 0);
    return std::vector<std::vector<int>>(size, skyscraperRow);
}

std::vector<std::vector<Nopes>> Board::makeNopes(std::size_t size)
{
    std::vector<Nopes> nopesRow(size, Nopes{static_cast<int>(size) - 1});
    return std::vector<std::vector<Nopes>>(size, nopesRow);
}

void Board::makeFields()
{
    mFields.reserve(skyscrapers.size());
    for (auto &row : mFields) {
        row.reserve(mFields.size());
    }
    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < skyscrapers.size(); ++y) {
        mFields[y].reserve(skyscrapers.size());
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < skyscrapers[y].size(); ++x) {
            mFields[y].emplace_back(Field{skyscrapers[y][x], nopes[y][x]});
        }
    }
}

void Board::makeRows()
{
    BorderIterator borderIterator{mFields.size()};

    std::size_t size = mFields.size() * 2;
    mRows.reserve(size);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++borderIterator) {
        mRows.emplace_back(Row{mFields, borderIterator.point(),
                               borderIterator.readDirection()});
    }
    connnectRowsWithCrossingRows();
}

void Board::connnectRowsWithCrossingRows()
{
    std::size_t boardSize = mRows.size() / 2;

    std::vector<int> targetRowsIdx(boardSize);
    std::iota(targetRowsIdx.begin(), targetRowsIdx.end(), boardSize);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mRows.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == mRows.size() / 2) {
            std::iota(targetRowsIdx.begin(), targetRowsIdx.end(), 0);
            std::reverse(targetRowsIdx.begin(), targetRowsIdx.end());
        }

        for (const auto &targetRowIdx : targetRowsIdx) {
            mRows[i].addCrossingRows(&mRows[targetRowIdx]);
        }
    }
}

void debug_print(Board &board, const std::string &title)
{
    std::cout << title << '\n';
    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < board.skyscrapers.size(); ++y) {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < board.skyscrapers[y].size(); ++x) {

            if (board.skyscrapers[y][x] != 0) {
                std::cout << std::setw(board.skyscrapers.size() * 2);
                std::cout << "V" + std::to_string(board.skyscrapers[y][x]);
            }
            else if (board.skyscrapers[y][x] == 0 &&
                     !board.nopes[y][x].isEmpty()) {
                auto nopes_set = board.nopes[y][x].values();
                std::vector<int> nopes(nopes_set.begin(), nopes_set.end());
                std::sort(nopes.begin(), nopes.end());

                std::string nopesStr;
                for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nopes.size(); ++i) {
                    nopesStr.append(std::to_string(nopes[i]));
                    if (i != nopes.size() - 1) {
                        nopesStr.push_back(',');
                    }
                }
                std::cout << std::setw(board.skyscrapers.size() * 2);
                std::cout << nopesStr;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << ' ';
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename Iterator> int visibleBuildings(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    int visibleBuildingsCount = 0;
    int highestSeen = 0;
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        if (*it != 0 && *it > highestSeen) {
            ++visibleBuildingsCount;
            highestSeen = *it;
        }
    }
    return visibleBuildingsCount;
}

bool rowsAreValid(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &skyscrapers,
                  std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t xi = 0; xi < size; xi++) {
        if (xi != x && skyscrapers[y][xi] == skyscrapers[y][x]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool columnsAreValid(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &skyscrapers,
                     std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t yi = 0; yi < size; yi++) {
        if (yi != y && skyscrapers[yi][x] == skyscrapers[y][x]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::tuple<int, int> getRowClues(const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t y,
                                 std::size_t size)
{
    int frontClue = clues[clues.size() - 1 - y];
    int backClue = clues[size + y];
    return {frontClue, backClue};
}

bool rowCluesAreValid(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &skyscrapers,
                      const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t y,
                      std::size_t size)
{
    auto [frontClue, backClue] = getRowClues(clues, y, size);

    if (frontClue == 0 && backClue == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    bool rowIsFull = std::find(skyscrapers[y].cbegin(), skyscrapers[y].cend(),
                               0) == skyscrapers[y].cend();

    if (!rowIsFull) {
        return true;
    }

    if (frontClue != 0) {
        auto frontVisible =
            visibleBuildings(skyscrapers[y].cbegin(), skyscrapers[y].cend());

        if (frontClue != frontVisible) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (backClue != 0) {
        auto backVisible =
            visibleBuildings(skyscrapers[y].crbegin(), skyscrapers[y].crend());

        if (backClue != backVisible) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::tuple<int, int> getColumnClues(const std::vector<int> &clues,
                                    std::size_t x, std::size_t size)
{
    int frontClue = clues[x];
    int backClue = clues[size * 3 - 1 - x];
    return {frontClue, backClue};
}

bool columnCluesAreValid(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &skyscrapers,
                         const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t x,
                         std::size_t size)
{
    auto [frontClue, backClue] = getColumnClues(clues, x, size);

    if (frontClue == 0 && backClue == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    std::vector<int> verticalSkyscrapers;
    verticalSkyscrapers.reserve(size);

    for (std::size_t yi = 0; yi < size; ++yi) {
        verticalSkyscrapers.emplace_back(skyscrapers[yi][x]);
    }

    bool columnIsFull =
        std::find(verticalSkyscrapers.cbegin(), verticalSkyscrapers.cend(),
                  0) == verticalSkyscrapers.cend();

    if (!columnIsFull) {
        return true;
    }

    if (frontClue != 0) {
        auto frontVisible = visibleBuildings(verticalSkyscrapers.cbegin(),
                                             verticalSkyscrapers.cend());
        if (frontClue != frontVisible) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (backClue != 0) {
        auto backVisible = visibleBuildings(verticalSkyscrapers.crbegin(),
                                            verticalSkyscrapers.crend());

        if (backClue != backVisible) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool skyscrapersAreValidPositioned(
    const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &skyscrapers,
    const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t x, std::size_t y,
    std::size_t size)
{
    if (!rowsAreValid(skyscrapers, x, y, size)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!columnsAreValid(skyscrapers, x, y, size)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!rowCluesAreValid(skyscrapers, clues, y, size)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!columnCluesAreValid(skyscrapers, clues, x, size)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool guessSkyscrapers(Board &board, const std::vector<int> &clues,
                      std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t size)
{
    if (x == size) {
        x = 0;
        y++;
    };
    if (y == size) {
        return true;
    }
    if (board.skyscrapers[y][x] != 0) {
        if (!skyscrapersAreValidPositioned(board.skyscrapers, clues, x, y,
                                           size)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (guessSkyscrapers(board, clues, x + 1, y, size)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (int trySkyscraper = 1;
         trySkyscraper <= static_cast<int>(board.skyscrapers.size());
         ++trySkyscraper) {

        if (board.nopes[y][x].contains(trySkyscraper)) {
            continue;
        }
        board.skyscrapers[y][x] = trySkyscraper;
        if (!skyscrapersAreValidPositioned(board.skyscrapers, clues, x, y,
                                           size)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (guessSkyscrapers(board, clues, x + 1, y, size)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    board.skyscrapers[y][x] = 0;
    return false;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>>
SolvePuzzle(const std::vector<int> &clues,
            std::vector<std::vector<int>> startingGrid, int)
{
    assert(clues.size() % 4 == 0);

    std::size_t boardSize = clues.size() / 4;

    auto clueHints = getClueHints(clues, boardSize);

    Board board{boardSize};

    board.insert(clueHints);
    board.insert(startingGrid);

    if (board.isSolved()) {
        return board.skyscrapers;
    }

    guessSkyscrapers(board, clues, 0, 0, board.skyscrapers.size());
    return board.skyscrapers;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> SolvePuzzle(const std::vector<int> &clues)
{
    return SolvePuzzle(clues, std::vector<std::vector<int>>{}, 0);
}

} // namespace codewarsbacktracking
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use more efficient containers

There are several areas where your code can be improved by changing the containers you are using to hold the data:

### Don't use nested `std::vector`s for 2D arrays

Instead of `std::vector<std::vector<Something>>`, use a `std::vector<Something>`. Make sure the size is big enough to hold the same number of elements of course. To look up the element at coordinates `x, y` of an `N * N` vector, use `[x + y * N]` as the array index.

### Store positions in a single `std::size_t`

Instead of passing `x` and `y` coordinates separately, consider passing an index into the flattened vector as described above. This saves a variable, and sometimes some calculations as well. For example:

```
if (x == size) {
    x = 0;
    y++;
}
if (y == size) {
    return true;
}
```

Can be replaced with:

```
if (index == size) {
    return true;
}
```

Assuming `size` is now the total number of elements in the grid.

### Store information efficiently in bitmasks

Instead of using a `std::unordered_set<int>` to remember a set of positions, use a [bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). You can use an `std::uint64_t` for this, and be able to handle sizes of up to 64, which I think will be more than you will ever need (maybe an `std::uint32_t` would also suffice).

## Only store essential data in classes

Avoid storing redundant data in classes. For example, a `Field` has a reference to the skyscraper height, the `Nopes`, and a boolean to indicate whether there is a skyscraper already at that field. But, you only need a single bitmask as mentioned above to replace `Nopes`. If only a single bit is left set in the bitmask, you know that that indicates the actual height of the skyscraper. Operations on bitmasks are very fast, and by reducing the amount of data stored per field you reduce memory bandwidth and have a bigger chance that things fit into the CPU's cache.

Note that with C++20 comes the [`<bit>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit), which has some helpful functions when dealing with bitmasks.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly you would use only a bitmask to store nopes and skyscrapers. Like in the beginning set all bits e.g b1111 for n=4 and when there is a nope mask it out like b0111.

Comment: Exactly. You could also invert the bits, so that a `1` is a nope, and then you can just initialize everything with zeroes, but I don't think it will matter much.

Comment: If you do `if (++index == size)` don't you then skip the first element on start of the backtracking?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `++` should not be used here.

Comment: I added the first optimization to the code. flatten the 2d array into a single vector but surprisingly it runs slower than before.

Comment: I made all the optimizations including the bitfield optimization but it good even worse. I wonder if I just implemented the bid fiddling with the bitfield wrong. I guess See here: https://github.com/SandroWissmann/Skyscrapers/tree/bitfield

Comment: It looks like you still have lots of loops over things that should not be necessary anymore with bitmasks. But if you want a proper review of the bitfield version, just go ahead and make a new question here on Code Review!

Comment: yes I will get into the code again to clean it up and post it soon.

Comment: Ok like promised I posted the changed code here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257451/skyscraper-solver-for-nxn-size-version-3