# Skyscraper Solver for NxN Size Version 3 (Using Bitmasks)

Tags: c++, performance, c++17

This is a follow up of [Skyscraper Solver for NxN Size Version 2 (Using Backtracking)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257197/skyscraper-solver-for-nxn-size-version-2-using-backtracking)

I followed the advice in the last Codereview and did the following optimizations:

- Implementation of the class `Field` using a single Bitmask wiht
  `std::uint32_t` to represent Skyscrapers and Nopes. To give you an
  idea for `n=4` the representation looks like this:

  ```
  b0000 0 Nopes = {}
  b0001 1 Nopes = 1
  b0010 2 Nopes = 2
  b0011 3 Nopes = 1, 2
  b0100 4 Nopes = 3
  b0101 5 Nopes = 1, 3
  b0110 6 Nopes = 2, 3
  b0111 7 Skyscraper = 4
  b1000 8 Nopes = 4
  b1001 9 Nopes = 1, 4
  b1010 10 Nopes = 2, 4
  b1011 11 Skyscraper = 3
  b1100 12 Nopes = 3, 4
  b1101 13 Skyscraper
  b1110 14 Skyscraper = 1
  b1111 15 Invalid all nope
  ```

  Now the idea was that now that we represent Nopes and Skyscrapers
  with a bitmask the size for each field should go down a lot. Before
  this optimization I used an extra `Nope` class which is an
  `std::unordered_set` and an int for representing the Skyscraper.

  So some of the old Nope class methods could get fused into the new `Field` class saving us
  the extra implementation and keeping track of all the `Nope` stuff.
- Storing the fields of the Board in an flat array. So instead of
  `std::vector<std::vector<Field>>` I know use `std::vector<Field>`.
  With the size of the puzzle we can still access each two dimensional
  position on the Board.

Now the bad news. With the optimization I was hoping the backtracking would solve the puzzles faster. Unfortunately the opposite happens. Now my solution is even more slow. I wonder if I just implemented the `Field` class with the Bitmask wrong.

So please let me know what stinks in terms of performance.

The full source code:

```
#include "codewarsbacktracking.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

namespace codewarsbacktracking {

struct ClueHints {
    ClueHints(std::size_t boardSize);
    ClueHints();

    void reverse();

    void removeNopesOnSkyscrapers();

    std::vector<int> skyscrapers{};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> nopes{};
};

ClueHints::ClueHints(std::size_t boardSize)
    : skyscrapers{std::vector<int>(boardSize, 0)},
      nopes{std::vector<std::vector<int>>(boardSize, std::vector<int>{})}
{
}

void ClueHints::reverse()
{
    std::reverse(skyscrapers.begin(), skyscrapers.end());
    std::reverse(nopes.begin(), nopes.end());
}

void ClueHints::removeNopesOnSkyscrapers()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < skyscrapers.size(); ++i) {
        if (skyscrapers[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        nopes[i].clear();
    }
}

std::optional<ClueHints> getClueHints(int clue, std::size_t boardSize)
{
    if (clue == 0) {
        return {};
    }

    ClueHints clueHints{boardSize};

    std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> nopes(boardSize,
                                               std::unordered_set<int>{});

    if (clue == static_cast<int>(boardSize)) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < boardSize; ++i) {
            clueHints.skyscrapers[i] = i + 1;
        }
    }
    else if (clue == 1) {
        clueHints.skyscrapers[0] = boardSize;
    }
    else if (clue == 2) {
        nopes[0].insert(boardSize);
        nopes[1].insert(boardSize - 1);
    }
    else {
        for (std::size_t fieldIdx = 0;
             fieldIdx < static_cast<std::size_t>(clue - 1); ++fieldIdx) {

            for (std::size_t nopeValue = boardSize;
                 nopeValue >= (boardSize - (clue - 2) + fieldIdx);
                 --nopeValue) {
                nopes[fieldIdx].insert(nopeValue);
            }
        }
    }

    assert(nopes.size() == clueHints.nopes.size());

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nopes.size(); ++i) {
        clueHints.nopes[i] = std::vector<int>(nopes[i].begin(), nopes[i].end());
    }
    return {clueHints};
}

std::optional<ClueHints> merge(std::optional<ClueHints> optFrontClueHints,
                               std::optional<ClueHints> optBackClueHints)
{
    if (!optFrontClueHints && !optBackClueHints) {
        return {};
    }
    if (!optFrontClueHints) {
        optBackClueHints->reverse();
        return optBackClueHints;
    }
    if (!optBackClueHints) {
        return optFrontClueHints;
    }

    auto size = optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers.size();
    ClueHints clueHints{size};

    assert(optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers.size() ==
           optFrontClueHints->nopes.size());
    assert(optBackClueHints->skyscrapers.size() ==
           optBackClueHints->nopes.size());
    assert(optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers.size() ==
           optBackClueHints->skyscrapers.size());

    optBackClueHints->reverse();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers.size(); ++i) {

        auto frontSkyscraper = optFrontClueHints->skyscrapers[i];
        auto backSkyscraper = optBackClueHints->skyscrapers[i];

        if (frontSkyscraper != 0 && backSkyscraper != 0) {
            assert(frontSkyscraper == backSkyscraper);
            clueHints.skyscrapers[i] = frontSkyscraper;
        }
        else if (frontSkyscraper != 0) {
            clueHints.skyscrapers[i] = frontSkyscraper;
            clueHints.nopes[i].clear();
        }
        else { // backSkyscraper != 0
            clueHints.skyscrapers[i] = backSkyscraper;
            clueHints.nopes[i].clear();
        }

        if (clueHints.skyscrapers[i] != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        std::unordered_set<int> nopes(optFrontClueHints->nopes[i].begin(),
                                      optFrontClueHints->nopes[i].end());
        nopes.insert(optBackClueHints->nopes[i].begin(),
                     optBackClueHints->nopes[i].end());
        clueHints.nopes[i] = std::vector<int>(nopes.begin(), nopes.end());
    }
    clueHints.removeNopesOnSkyscrapers();
    return {clueHints};
}

void mergeClueHintsPerRow(std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>> &clueHints)
{
    std::size_t startOffset = clueHints.size() / 4 * 3 - 1;
    std::size_t offset = startOffset;

    for (std::size_t frontIdx = 0; frontIdx < clueHints.size() / 2;
         ++frontIdx, offset -= 2) {

        if (frontIdx == clueHints.size() / 4) {
            offset = startOffset;
        }

        int backIdx = frontIdx + offset;

        clueHints[frontIdx] = merge(clueHints[frontIdx], clueHints[backIdx]);
    }
    clueHints.erase(clueHints.begin() + clueHints.size() / 2, clueHints.end());
}

std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>>
getClueHints(const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t boardSize)
{
    std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>> clueHints;
    clueHints.reserve(clues.size());

    for (const auto &clue : clues) {
        clueHints.emplace_back(getClueHints(clue, boardSize));
    }
    mergeClueHintsPerRow(clueHints);
    return clueHints;
}

template <typename It> int missingNumberInSequence(It begin, It end)
{
    int n = std::distance(begin, end) + 1;
    double projectedSum = (n + 1) * (n / 2.0);
    int actualSum = std::accumulate(begin, end, 0);
    return projectedSum - actualSum;
}

using BitmaskType = std::uint32_t;

/*
Example size = 4

b0000 0 Nopes = {}
b0001 1 Nopes = 1
b0010 2 Nopes = 2
b0011 3 Nopes = 1, 2
b0100 4 Nopes = 3
b0101 5 Nopes = 1, 3
b0110 6 Nopes = 2, 3
b0111 7 Skyscraper = 4
b1000 8 Nopes = 4
b1001 9 Nopes = 1, 4
b1010 10 Nopes = 2, 4
b1011 11 Skyscraper = 3
b1100 12 Nopes = 3, 4
b1101 13 Skyscraper
b1110 14 Skyscraper = 1
b1111 15 Invalid all nope
*/

class Field {
public:
    Field(std::size_t size);

    void insertSkyscraper(int skyscraper);
    void insertNope(int nope);
    void insertNopes(const std::vector<int> &nopes);

    int skyscraper() const;
    std::vector<int> nopes() const;

    bool hasSkyscraper() const;

    bool containsNope(int value) const;
    bool containsNopes(const std::vector<int> &values);

    BitmaskType bitmask() const;
    void setBitmask(BitmaskType bitmask);

private:
    bool bitIsToggled(BitmaskType bitmask, int bit) const;

    BitmaskType mBitmask{0};
    std::size_t mSize;

    friend inline bool operator==(const Field &lhs, const Field &rhs);
    friend inline bool operator!=(const Field &lhs, const Field &rhs);
};

inline bool operator==(const Field &lhs, const Field &rhs)
{
    return lhs.mBitmask == rhs.mBitmask;
}
inline bool operator!=(const Field &lhs, const Field &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

Field::Field(std::size_t size) : mSize{size}
{
}

void Field::insertSkyscraper(int skyscraper)
{
    assert(skyscraper > 0 && skyscraper <= static_cast<int>(mSize));
    BitmaskType mask = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(mSize); ++i) {
        if (i != skyscraper - 1) {
            mBitmask |= mask;
        }
        mask <<= 1;
    }
}

void Field::insertNope(int nope)
{
    assert(nope > 0 && nope <= static_cast<int>(mSize));
    mBitmask |= 1 << (nope - 1);
}

void Field::insertNopes(const std::vector<int> &nopes)
{
    for (const auto nope : nopes) {
        insertNope(nope);
    }
}

int Field::skyscraper() const
{
    if (!hasSkyscraper()) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mSize; ++i) {
        if (!(bitIsToggled(mBitmask, i))) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

std::vector<int> Field::nopes() const
{
    std::vector<int> nopes;
    nopes.reserve(mSize - 1);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mSize; ++i) {
        if (bitIsToggled(mBitmask, i)) {
            nopes.emplace_back(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return nopes;
}

bool Field::hasSkyscraper() const
{
    bool foundZero = false;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mSize; ++i) {
        if (!(bitIsToggled(mBitmask, i))) {
            if (!foundZero) {
                foundZero = true;
            }
            else { // found more than one zero so no skyscraper present
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Field::containsNope(int value) const
{
    return bitIsToggled(mBitmask, value - 1);
}

bool Field::containsNopes(const std::vector<int> &values)
{
    for (const auto &value : values) {
        if (!containsNope(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

BitmaskType Field::bitmask() const
{
    return mBitmask;
}

void Field::setBitmask(BitmaskType bitmask)
{
    mBitmask = bitmask;
}

bool Field::bitIsToggled(BitmaskType bitmask, int bit) const
{
    return bitmask & (1 << bit);
}

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

inline bool operator==(const Point &lhs, const Point &rhs)
{
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}
inline bool operator!=(const Point &lhs, const Point &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

enum class ReadDirection { topToBottom, rightToLeft };

void nextDirection(ReadDirection &readDirection);

void advanceToNextPosition(Point &point, ReadDirection readDirection,
                           int clueIdx);

void nextDirection(ReadDirection &readDirection)
{
    assert(readDirection != ReadDirection::rightToLeft);
    int dir = static_cast<int>(readDirection);
    ++dir;
    readDirection = static_cast<ReadDirection>(dir);
}

void advanceToNextPosition(Point &point, ReadDirection readDirection,
                           int clueIdx)
{
    if (clueIdx == 0) {
        return;
    }
    switch (readDirection) {
    case ReadDirection::topToBottom:
        ++point.x;
        break;
    case ReadDirection::rightToLeft:
        ++point.y;
        break;
    }
}

class Row {
public:
    Row(std::vector<Field> &fields, std::size_t size, const Point &startPoint,
        const ReadDirection &readDirection);

    void insertSkyscraper(int pos, int skyscraper);

    std::size_t size() const;

    void addCrossingRows(Row *crossingRow);

    bool hasOnlyOneNopeField() const;
    void addLastMissingSkyscraper();

    void addNopesToAllNopeFields(int nope);

    bool allFieldsContainSkyscraper() const;

    int skyscraperCount() const;
    int nopeCount(int nope) const;

    void guessSkyscraperOutOfNeighbourNopes();

    enum class Direction { front, back };

    bool hasSkyscrapers(const std::vector<int> &skyscrapers,
                        Direction direction) const;
    bool hasNopes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &nopes,
                  Direction direction) const;

    void addSkyscrapers(const std::vector<int> &skyscrapers,
                        Direction direction);
    void addNopes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &nopes,
                  Direction direction);

    std::vector<Field *> getFields() const;

private:
    template <typename SkyIterator, typename FieldIterator>
    bool hasSkyscrapers(SkyIterator skyItBegin, SkyIterator skyItEnd,
                        FieldIterator fieldItBegin,
                        FieldIterator fieldItEnd) const;

    template <typename NopesIterator, typename FieldIterator>
    bool hasNopes(NopesIterator nopesItBegin, NopesIterator nopesItEnd,
                  FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd) const;

    template <typename SkyIterator, typename FieldIterator>
    void addSkyscrapers(SkyIterator skyItBegin, SkyIterator skyItEnd,
                        FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd);

    template <typename NopesIterator, typename FieldIterator>
    void addNopes(NopesIterator nopesItBegin, NopesIterator nopesItEnd,
                  FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd);

    template <typename IteratorType>
    void insertSkyscraper(IteratorType it, int skyscraper);

    template <typename IteratorType> void insertNope(IteratorType it, int nope);

    template <typename IteratorType>
    void insertNopes(IteratorType it, const std::vector<int> &nopes);

    int getIdx(std::vector<Field *>::const_iterator cit) const;
    int getIdx(std::vector<Field *>::const_reverse_iterator crit) const;

    std::vector<Field *> getRowFields(const ReadDirection &readDirection,
                                      std::vector<Field> &boardFields,
                                      std::size_t size,
                                      const Point &startPoint);

    bool onlyOneFieldWithoutNope(int nope) const;

    bool nopeExistsAsSkyscraperInFields(const std::vector<Field *> &rowFields,
                                        int nope) const;

    std::optional<int> nopeValueInAllButOneField() const;

    void insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(int nope);

    bool hasSkyscraper(int skyscraper) const;

    std::vector<Row *> mCrossingRows;
    std::vector<Field *> mRowFields;
};

Row::Row(std::vector<Field> &fields, std::size_t size, const Point &startPoint,
         const ReadDirection &readDirection)
    : mRowFields{getRowFields(readDirection, fields, size, startPoint)}
{
}

void Row::insertSkyscraper(int pos, int skyscraper)
{
    assert(pos >= 0 && pos < static_cast<int>(mRowFields.size()));
    assert(skyscraper > 0 && skyscraper <= static_cast<int>(mRowFields.size()));
    auto it = mRowFields.begin() + pos;
    insertSkyscraper(it, skyscraper);
}

std::size_t Row::size() const
{
    return mRowFields.size();
}

void Row::addCrossingRows(Row *crossingRow)
{
    assert(crossingRow != nullptr);
    assert(mCrossingRows.size() < size());
    mCrossingRows.push_back(crossingRow);
}

bool Row::hasOnlyOneNopeField() const
{
    return skyscraperCount() == static_cast<int>(size() - 1);
}

void Row::addLastMissingSkyscraper()
{
    assert(hasOnlyOneNopeField());

    auto nopeFieldIt = mRowFields.end();
    std::vector<int> sequence;
    sequence.reserve(size() - 1);

    for (auto it = mRowFields.begin(); it != mRowFields.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            sequence.emplace_back((*it)->skyscraper());
        }
        else {
            nopeFieldIt = it;
        }
    }
    assert(nopeFieldIt != mRowFields.end());
    assert(skyscraperCount() == static_cast<int>(sequence.size()));

    auto missingValue =
        missingNumberInSequence(sequence.begin(), sequence.end());

    assert(missingValue >= 0 && missingValue <= static_cast<int>(size()));
    insertSkyscraper(nopeFieldIt, missingValue);
}

void Row::addNopesToAllNopeFields(int nope)
{
    for (auto it = mRowFields.begin(); it != mRowFields.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            continue;
        }
        insertNope(it, nope);
    }
}

bool Row::allFieldsContainSkyscraper() const
{
    return skyscraperCount() == static_cast<int>(size());
}

int Row::skyscraperCount() const
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto cit = mRowFields.cbegin(); cit != mRowFields.cend(); ++cit) {
        if ((*cit)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int Row::nopeCount(int nope) const
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto cit = mRowFields.cbegin(); cit != mRowFields.cend(); ++cit) {
        if ((*cit)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((*cit)->containsNope(nope)) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void Row::guessSkyscraperOutOfNeighbourNopes()
{
    for (;;) {
        auto optNope = nopeValueInAllButOneField();
        if (!optNope) {
            break;
        }
        insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(*optNope);
    }
}

bool Row::hasSkyscrapers(const std::vector<int> &skyscrapers,
                         Row::Direction direction) const
{
    if (direction == Direction::front) {
        return hasSkyscrapers(skyscrapers.cbegin(), skyscrapers.cend(),
                              mRowFields.cbegin(), mRowFields.cend());
    }
    return hasSkyscrapers(skyscrapers.cbegin(), skyscrapers.cend(),
                          mRowFields.crbegin(), mRowFields.crend());
}

bool Row::hasNopes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &nopes,
                   Direction direction) const
{
    if (direction == Direction::front) {
        return hasNopes(nopes.cbegin(), nopes.cend(), mRowFields.cbegin(),
                        mRowFields.cend());
    }
    return hasNopes(nopes.cbegin(), nopes.cend(), mRowFields.crbegin(),
                    mRowFields.crend());
}

void Row::addSkyscrapers(const std::vector<int> &skyscrapers,
                         Direction direction)
{
    if (direction == Direction::front) {
        addSkyscrapers(skyscrapers.begin(), skyscrapers.end(),
                       mRowFields.begin(), mRowFields.end());
    }
    else {
        addSkyscrapers(skyscrapers.begin(), skyscrapers.end(),
                       mRowFields.rbegin(), mRowFields.rend());
    }
}
void Row::addNopes(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &nopes,
                   Direction direction)
{
    if (direction == Direction::front) {
        addNopes(nopes.begin(), nopes.end(), mRowFields.begin(),
                 mRowFields.end());
    }
    else {
        addNopes(nopes.begin(), nopes.end(), mRowFields.rbegin(),
                 mRowFields.rend());
    }
}

std::vector<Field *> Row::getFields() const
{
    return mRowFields;
}

template <typename SkyIterator, typename FieldIterator>
bool Row::hasSkyscrapers(SkyIterator skyItBegin, SkyIterator skyItEnd,
                         FieldIterator fieldItBegin,
                         FieldIterator fieldItEnd) const
{
    auto skyIt = skyItBegin;
    for (auto fieldIt = fieldItBegin;
         fieldIt != fieldItEnd && skyIt != skyItEnd; ++fieldIt, ++skyIt) {
        if (*skyIt == 0 && (*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((*fieldIt)->skyscraper() != *skyIt) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename NopesIterator, typename FieldIterator>
bool Row::hasNopes(NopesIterator nopesItBegin, NopesIterator nopesItEnd,
                   FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd) const
{
    auto nopesIt = nopesItBegin;
    for (auto fieldIt = fieldItBegin;
         fieldIt != fieldItEnd && nopesIt != nopesItEnd; ++fieldIt, ++nopesIt) {

        if (nopesIt->empty()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(*fieldIt)->containsNopes(*nopesIt)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename SkyIterator, typename FieldIterator>
void Row::addSkyscrapers(SkyIterator skyItBegin, SkyIterator skyItEnd,
                         FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd)
{
    auto skyIt = skyItBegin;
    for (auto fieldIt = fieldItBegin;
         fieldIt != fieldItEnd && skyIt != skyItEnd; ++fieldIt, ++skyIt) {
        if (*skyIt == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        insertSkyscraper(fieldIt, *skyIt);
    }
}

template <typename NopesIterator, typename FieldIterator>
void Row::addNopes(NopesIterator nopesItBegin, NopesIterator nopesItEnd,
                   FieldIterator fieldItBegin, FieldIterator fieldItEnd)
{
    auto nopesIt = nopesItBegin;
    for (auto fieldIt = fieldItBegin;
         fieldIt != fieldItEnd && nopesIt != nopesItEnd; ++fieldIt, ++nopesIt) {
        if (nopesIt->empty()) {
            continue;
        }
        insertNopes(fieldIt, *nopesIt);
    }
}

template <typename FieldIterator>
void Row::insertSkyscraper(FieldIterator fieldIt, int skyscraper)
{
    assert(mCrossingRows.size() == size());

    if ((*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
        return;
    }
    (*fieldIt)->insertSkyscraper(skyscraper);

    if (hasOnlyOneNopeField()) {
        addLastMissingSkyscraper();
    }
    addNopesToAllNopeFields(skyscraper);

    int idx = getIdx(fieldIt);

    if (mCrossingRows[idx]->hasOnlyOneNopeField()) {
        mCrossingRows[idx]->addLastMissingSkyscraper();
    }

    mCrossingRows[idx]->addNopesToAllNopeFields(skyscraper);
}

template <typename FieldIterator>
void Row::insertNope(FieldIterator fieldIt, int nope)
{
    if ((*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
        return;
    }
    if ((*fieldIt)->containsNope(nope)) {
        return;
    }

    bool hasSkyscraperBefore = (*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper();
    (*fieldIt)->insertNope(nope);

    // skyscraper was added so we have to add nopes to the neighbours
    // probaly could insert only nopes directly
    if (!hasSkyscraperBefore && (*fieldIt)->hasSkyscraper()) {
        insertSkyscraper(fieldIt, (*fieldIt)->skyscraper());
    }

    if (onlyOneFieldWithoutNope(nope)) {
        insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(nope);
    }

    int idx = getIdx(fieldIt);

    if (mCrossingRows[idx]->onlyOneFieldWithoutNope(nope)) {
        mCrossingRows[idx]->insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(nope);
    }
}

template <typename IteratorType>
void Row::insertNopes(IteratorType it, const std::vector<int> &nopes)
{
    for (const auto &nope : nopes) {
        insertNope(it, nope);
    }
}

int Row::getIdx(std::vector<Field *>::const_iterator cit) const
{
    return std::distance(mRowFields.cbegin(), cit);
}

int Row::getIdx(std::vector<Field *>::const_reverse_iterator crit) const
{
    return size() - std::distance(mRowFields.crbegin(), crit) - 1;
}

std::vector<Field *> Row::getRowFields(const ReadDirection &readDirection,
                                       std::vector<Field> &boardFields,
                                       std::size_t size,
                                       const Point &startPoint)
{
    std::vector<Field *> fields;
    fields.reserve(size);
    std::size_t x = startPoint.x;
    std::size_t y = startPoint.y;

    if (readDirection == ReadDirection::topToBottom) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            fields.emplace_back(&boardFields[x + y * size]);
            ++y;
        }
    }
    else { // ReadDirection::rightToLeft
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            fields.emplace_back(&boardFields[x + y * size]);
            --x;
        }
    }
    return fields;
}

bool Row::onlyOneFieldWithoutNope(int nope) const
{
    if (nopeExistsAsSkyscraperInFields(mRowFields, nope)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (nopeCount(nope) < static_cast<int>(size()) - skyscraperCount() - 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool Row::nopeExistsAsSkyscraperInFields(const std::vector<Field *> &rowFields,
                                         int nope) const
{
    auto cit = std::find_if(
        rowFields.cbegin(), rowFields.cend(),
        [nope](const auto &field) { return field->skyscraper() == nope; });
    return cit != rowFields.cend();
}

std::optional<int> Row::nopeValueInAllButOneField() const
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> nopeAndCount;

    for (auto cit = mRowFields.cbegin(); cit != mRowFields.cend(); ++cit) {
        if (!(*cit)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            auto nopes = (*cit)->nopes();
            for (const auto &nope : nopes) {
                if (hasSkyscraper(nope)) {
                    continue;
                }
                ++nopeAndCount[nope];
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto cit = nopeAndCount.cbegin(); cit != nopeAndCount.end(); ++cit) {
        if (cit->second == static_cast<int>(size()) - skyscraperCount() - 1) {
            return {cit->first};
        }
    }
    return {};
}

void Row::insertSkyscraperToFirstFieldWithoutNope(int nope)
{
    for (auto it = mRowFields.begin(); it != mRowFields.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it)->hasSkyscraper()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!(*it)->containsNope(nope)) {
            insertSkyscraper(it, nope);
            return; // there can be max one skyscraper per row;
        }
    }
}

bool Row::hasSkyscraper(int skyscraper) const
{
    for (const auto &field : mRowFields) {
        if (field->skyscraper() == skyscraper) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

class BorderIterator {
public:
    BorderIterator(std::size_t boardSize);

    Point point() const;
    ReadDirection readDirection() const;

    BorderIterator &operator++();

private:
    int mIdx = 0;
    std::size_t mBoardSize;
    Point mPoint{0, 0};
    ReadDirection mReadDirection{ReadDirection::topToBottom};
};

BorderIterator::BorderIterator(std::size_t boardSize) : mBoardSize{boardSize}
{
}

Point BorderIterator::point() const
{
    return mPoint;
}

ReadDirection BorderIterator::readDirection() const
{
    return mReadDirection;
}

BorderIterator &BorderIterator::operator++()
{
    ++mIdx;
    if (mIdx == static_cast<int>(2 * mBoardSize)) {
        return *this;
    }
    if (mIdx != 0 && mIdx % mBoardSize == 0) {
        nextDirection(mReadDirection);
    }

    advanceToNextPosition(mPoint, mReadDirection, mIdx % mBoardSize);
    return *this;
}

struct Board {
    Board(std::size_t size);

    void insert(const std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>> &clueHints);

    void insert(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &startingSkyscrapers);

    bool isSolved() const;

    std::vector<Field> fields;

    std::vector<Row> mRows;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> skyscrapers2d() const;

    std::size_t size() const;

private:
    void makeRows();
    void connnectRowsWithCrossingRows();

    std::size_t mSize;
};

Board::Board(std::size_t size)
    : fields{std::vector<Field>(size * size, Field{size})}, mSize{size}
{
    makeRows();
}

void Board::insert(const std::vector<std::optional<ClueHints>> &clueHints)
{
    assert(clueHints.size() == mRows.size());

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < clueHints.size(); ++i) {
        if (!clueHints[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        mRows[i].addNopes(clueHints[i]->nopes, Row::Direction::front);
        mRows[i].addSkyscrapers(clueHints[i]->skyscrapers,
                                Row::Direction::front);
    }
}

void Board::insert(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &startingSkyscrapers)
{
    if (startingSkyscrapers.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    std::size_t boardSize = mRows.size() / 2;
    assert(startingSkyscrapers.size() == boardSize);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < startingSkyscrapers.size(); ++i) {
        mRows[i + boardSize].addSkyscrapers(startingSkyscrapers[i],
                                            Row::Direction::back);
    }
}

bool Board::isSolved() const
{
    std::size_t endVerticalRows = mRows.size() / 2;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < endVerticalRows; ++i) {
        if (!mRows[i].allFieldsContainSkyscraper()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> Board::skyscrapers2d() const
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> skyscrapers2d(mSize, std::vector<int>());

    std::size_t j = 0;
    skyscrapers2d[j].reserve(mSize);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < fields.size(); ++i) {
        if (i != 0 && i % mSize == 0) {
            ++j;
            skyscrapers2d[j].reserve(mSize);
        }
        skyscrapers2d[j].emplace_back(fields[i].skyscraper());
    }
    return skyscrapers2d;
}

std::size_t Board::size() const
{
    return mSize;
}

void Board::makeRows()
{
    BorderIterator borderIterator{mSize};

    std::size_t rowSize = mSize * 2;
    mRows.reserve(rowSize);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i, ++borderIterator) {
        mRows.emplace_back(Row{fields, mSize, borderIterator.point(),
                               borderIterator.readDirection()});
    }
    connnectRowsWithCrossingRows();
}

void Board::connnectRowsWithCrossingRows()
{
    std::size_t boardSize = mRows.size() / 2;

    std::vector<int> targetRowsIdx(boardSize);
    std::iota(targetRowsIdx.begin(), targetRowsIdx.end(), boardSize);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mRows.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == mRows.size() / 2) {
            std::iota(targetRowsIdx.begin(), targetRowsIdx.end(), 0);
            std::reverse(targetRowsIdx.begin(), targetRowsIdx.end());
        }

        for (const auto &targetRowIdx : targetRowsIdx) {
            mRows[i].addCrossingRows(&mRows[targetRowIdx]);
        }
    }
}

void debug_print(Board &board, const std::string &title)
{
    std::cout << title << '\n';

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < board.fields.size(); ++i) {

        if (i % board.size() == 0 && i != 0) {
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

        if (board.fields[i].skyscraper() != 0) {
            std::cout << std::setw(board.size() * 2);
            std::cout << "V" + std::to_string(board.fields[i].skyscraper());
        }
        else if (board.fields[i].skyscraper() == 0 &&
                 !board.fields[i].nopes().empty()) {
            auto nopes_set = board.fields[i].nopes();
            std::vector<int> nopes(nopes_set.begin(), nopes_set.end());
            std::sort(nopes.begin(), nopes.end());

            std::string nopesStr;
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nopes.size(); ++i) {
                nopesStr.append(std::to_string(nopes[i]));
                if (i != nopes.size() - 1) {
                    nopesStr.push_back(',');
                }
            }
            std::cout << std::setw(board.size() * 2);
            std::cout << nopesStr;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename FieldIterator>
int visibleBuildings(FieldIterator begin, FieldIterator end)
{
    int visibleBuildingsCount = 0;
    int highestSeen = 0;
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        if (it->skyscraper() != 0 && it->skyscraper() > highestSeen) {
            ++visibleBuildingsCount;
            highestSeen = it->skyscraper();
        }
    }
    return visibleBuildingsCount;
}

bool rowsAreValid(const std::vector<Field> &fields, std::size_t index,
                  std::size_t rowSize)
{
    std::size_t row = index / rowSize;
    for (std::size_t currIndex = row * rowSize; currIndex < (row + 1) * rowSize;
         ++currIndex) {
        if (currIndex == index) {
            continue;
        }
        if (fields[currIndex].skyscraper() == fields[index].skyscraper()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool columnsAreValid(const std::vector<Field> &fields, std::size_t index,
                     std::size_t rowSize)
{
    std::size_t column = index % rowSize;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) {
        std::size_t currIndex = column + i * rowSize;
        if (currIndex == index) {
            continue;
        }
        if (fields[currIndex].skyscraper() == fields[index].skyscraper()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::tuple<int, int> getRowClues(const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t row,
                                 std::size_t rowSize)
{
    int frontClue = clues[clues.size() - 1 - row];
    int backClue = clues[rowSize + row];
    return {frontClue, backClue};
}

bool rowCluesAreValid(const std::vector<Field> &fields,
                      const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t index,
                      std::size_t rowSize)
{
    std::size_t row = index / rowSize;

    auto [frontClue, backClue] = getRowClues(clues, row, rowSize);

    if (frontClue == 0 && backClue == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    std::size_t rowIndexBegin = row * rowSize;
    std::size_t rowIndexEnd = (row + 1) * rowSize;

    auto citBegin = fields.cbegin() + rowIndexBegin;
    auto citEnd = fields.cbegin() + rowIndexEnd;

    bool rowIsFull = std::find_if(citBegin, citEnd, [](const Field &field) {
                         return !field.hasSkyscraper();
                     }) == citEnd;

    if (!rowIsFull) {
        return true;
    }

    if (frontClue != 0) {
        auto frontVisible = visibleBuildings(citBegin, citEnd);

        if (frontClue != frontVisible) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    auto critBegin = std::make_reverse_iterator(citEnd);
    auto critEnd = std::make_reverse_iterator(citBegin);

    if (backClue != 0) {
        auto backVisible = visibleBuildings(critBegin, critEnd);

        if (backClue != backVisible) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::tuple<int, int> getColumnClues(const std::vector<int> &clues,
                                    std::size_t x, std::size_t size)
{
    int frontClue = clues[x];
    int backClue = clues[size * 3 - 1 - x];
    return {frontClue, backClue};
}

bool columnCluesAreValid(const std::vector<Field> &fields,
                         const std::vector<int> &clues, std::size_t index,
                         std::size_t rowSize)
{
    std::size_t column = index % rowSize;

    auto [frontClue, backClue] = getColumnClues(clues, column, rowSize);

    if (frontClue == 0 && backClue == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    std::vector<Field> verticalFields;
    verticalFields.reserve(rowSize);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) {
        verticalFields.emplace_back(fields[column + i * rowSize]);
    }

    bool columnIsFull =
        std::find_if(verticalFields.cbegin(), verticalFields.cend(),
                     [](const Field &field) {
                         return !field.hasSkyscraper();
                     }) == verticalFields.cend();

    if (!columnIsFull) {
        return true;
    }

    if (frontClue != 0) {
        auto frontVisible =
            visibleBuildings(verticalFields.cbegin(), verticalFields.cend());
        if (frontClue != frontVisible) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (backClue != 0) {
        auto backVisible =
            visibleBuildings(verticalFields.crbegin(), verticalFields.crend());

        if (backClue != backVisible) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool skyscrapersAreValidPositioned(const std::vector<Field> &fields,
                                   const std::vector<int> &clues,
                                   std::size_t index, std::size_t rowSize)
{
    if (!rowsAreValid(fields, index, rowSize)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!columnsAreValid(fields, index, rowSize)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!rowCluesAreValid(fields, clues, index, rowSize)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!columnCluesAreValid(fields, clues, index, rowSize)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool guessSkyscrapers(Board &board, const std::vector<int> &clues,
                      std::size_t index, std::size_t countOfElements,
                      std::size_t rowSize)
{
    if (index == countOfElements) {
        return true;
    }

    if (board.fields[index].skyscraper() != 0) {
        if (!skyscrapersAreValidPositioned(board.fields, clues, index,
                                           rowSize)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (guessSkyscrapers(board, clues, index + 1, countOfElements,
                             rowSize)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    auto oldBitmask = board.fields[index].bitmask();
    for (int trySkyscraper = 1; trySkyscraper <= static_cast<int>(rowSize);
         ++trySkyscraper) {

        if (board.fields[index].containsNope(trySkyscraper)) {
            continue;
        }
        board.fields[index].insertSkyscraper(trySkyscraper);
        if (!skyscrapersAreValidPositioned(board.fields, clues, index,
                                           rowSize)) {
            board.fields[index].setBitmask(oldBitmask);
            continue;
        }
        if (guessSkyscrapers(board, clues, index + 1, countOfElements,
                             rowSize)) {
            return true;
        }
        board.fields[index].setBitmask(oldBitmask);
    }
    board.fields[index].setBitmask(oldBitmask);
    return false;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>>
SolvePuzzle(const std::vector<int> &clues,
            std::vector<std::vector<int>> startingGrid, int)
{
    assert(clues.size() % 4 == 0);

    std::size_t boardSize = clues.size() / 4;

    auto clueHints = getClueHints(clues, boardSize);

    Board board{boardSize};

    board.insert(clueHints);
    board.insert(startingGrid);

    if (board.isSolved()) {
        return board.skyscrapers2d();
    }
    guessSkyscrapers(board, clues, 0, board.fields.size(), board.size());

    return board.skyscrapers2d();
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> SolvePuzzle(const std::vector<int> &clues)
{
    return SolvePuzzle(clues, std::vector<std::vector<int>>{}, 0);
}

} // namespace codewarsbacktracking
```

Additional things like the unit test can be found [here](https://github.com/SandroWissmann/Skyscrapers/tree/bitfield)

Answer (score 1):

My overall impression of this code is that you are trying too hard to add abstractions to the code, but are not paying attention to performance. Of course, the trick is to find the right balance between the two. It might be an interesting excercise to write a solution to the problem in C, where it is more obvious when you try to do something inefficient, and then try to convert it back to C++ by finding out which pieces of code can be replaced by use of standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), and your own classes if there is nothing appropriate in the STL. Here is a list of some more specific problems that could be addressed:

## Avoid nested `std::vector`s

You are still nesting `std::vector`s, for eaxmple `ClueHint::nopes`. There's also a less obvious one: `Board::mRows` is a vector of `Row`s, but each `Row` contains a `std::vector<Field *>`. So this is effectively a nested vector again.

## Don't store redundant data

There is a big issue with `class Row`. It is storing a lot of redundant data. The only thing you need to know to be able to access a row on the board is (a reference to) the `Board` itself, and the number and direction of the row. If you really want to have a `class Row` to represent a row on the board, then you should make it work like a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) or [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Another issue is with `class Field`. It stores the bitmask of nopes, but also the size of the bitmask. The problem is that the size is the same for all the field in the board, so now you are storing a lot of redundant information. While the bitmask is 32 bits, `mSize` is a `std::size_t` so will most likely be 64 bits, and due to alignment restrictions, that means your `Field` will now be 128 bits large, 4 times more than necessary. I recommend you remove `mSize` from this class and just pass it to member functions that need to know the size.

## Use bitmasks efficiently

The whole point of bitmasks is that [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on them are very cheap. In particular, you don't have to set or reset one bit at a time, you can apply a whole mask in one go. For example, `Field::insertSkyscraper` contains a `for`-loop to fill in `mBitmask` one bit at a time, but you can do that much more efficiently like so:

```
void Field::insertSkyscraper(int skyscraper)
{
    mBitmask = 1 << (skyscraper - 1); // set just the bit corresponding to skyscraper
    mBitmask ^= (1 << mSize) - 1;     // invert all bits up to the size of the board
}
```

The above still requires the size to be known, but you actually don't care about the higher bits until you want to check if a field has only one valid skyscraper height left. So you can replace this function with:

```
void Field::insertSkyscraper(int skyscraper)
{
    mBitmask = ~(1 << (skyscraper - 1));
}
```

Looking at the code, it seems that it might actually be more efficient to store the bits inverted. The reason is that counting bits might not be as efficient, since not all CPUs doesn't support it in hardware (althought contemporary most CPUs do), and that you C++20 to get [`std::popcount()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount). If you invert the bits, then to check if only one possible skyscraper height is left on a field, you only have to [check if exactly one bit is set](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2), which is very simple to do yourself (C++20 gives us [`std::has_single_bit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit)).

Alternatively:

## Consider replacing `Field` with a `std::bitset`

Your `class Field` is basically reimplementing the features of [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Consider just using the latter directly:

```
std::vector<std::bitset<32>> fields;
```

## Be consistent naming things

Why are some member variable names prefixed with an `m`, but others are not? Why are some functions using [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), but others [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)? Try to be more consistent. Especially if you use prefixes to distinguish member variables from local or global variables, it stops being useful the moment you don't do this consistently.

Also, `ClueHint` is redundant, either name it a `Clue` or a `Hint`.

## Avoid redundant `std::optional`s

A `std::optional` is sometimes necessary if the type you want to return doesn't have a way to represent invalid/empty/none. However, `std::optional<ClueHints>` seems redundant, since a `ClueHint` can just have empty `skyscraper` and `nopes` variables, and that seems to me to be equivalent to saying there is no clue. Note that `std::optional<>` won't make things more efficient; it always reserves space for the whole type.

Comment: Member variables which are private are prefixed with an `m`. The public ones are not. The camelCase snake_case comes because the declaration of the method SolvePuzzle comes from codewars and is snake_case but I don't wanted to follow that style. Beside that many good advices. I will come back to it when I made all the changes.

Comment: Ah, I guess that makes sense then, I hadn't seen the convention to only use `m` for `private` member variables before.

Comment: beside replacing the bitmask with `std::bitset` I tried out all your suggestions but I don't see any speed improvements. At least the code got more readable. Are you sure there is not maybe also something wrong with the backtracking algorithm itself? Too me it looks like it just has to much insertions to do for certain puzzles.